# copying different excel files rows in one folder with similar A1 cell into one master file via vba (code not working)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Unfortunately I'm not much of a VBA expert, however I have managed to gather these codes from different websites.
I'm trying to get an Automation System running in excel and currently I'm able to send specific rows from an Excel sheet as attachment to each email mentioned in that row. Using this code:

```
Sub Send_Row_direct()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet
Dim Cws As Worksheet
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long

On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
Set Ash = ActiveSheet

'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:AF" & Ash.Rows.Count)
FieldNum = 2    'Filter column = B because the filter range start in column A

'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=False

'Count of the unique values + the header cell
Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

'If there are unique values start the loop
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

        'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
        If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

            'Copy the visible data in a new workbook
            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

            rng.Copy
            With NewWB.Sheets(1)
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                .Cells(1).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Create a file name
            TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
            TempFileName = "KBB_taskforce_assignment_on_" _
                         & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                'You use Excel 97-2003
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
            Else
                'You use Excel 2007-2016
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If

            'Save, Mail, Close and Delete the file
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With NewWB
                .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName _
                      & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
                    .Subject = Range("F2")
                    .Attachments.Add NewWB.FullName
                    .Body = Range("G2")
                    .send  'Or use Send
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
                .Close savechanges:=False
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
        End If

        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next Rnum
End If
cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With End Sub
```

Lets say the emails come back with the attachments and I have saved them all in one Folder.

Now I need a VBA code to read through these attachments, which all are stored in a folder, and show the rows which have similar values in cell `A2`.
The current code that I have managed to setup does the job perfectly with any other Excel file. But when it starts processing the auto made files by my VBA code it runs into Error 91. The line which the error is at is `CopyRange.Select`
and when removing it I will get another error at  `CopyRange.Copy MasterSht.Cells(MasterWBShtLstRw + 1, 1)` and when removing this line I will get no rows copied into my master file.

The Code is below :

```
Option Explicit Sub CopyToMasterFile11()

Dim MasterWB As Workbook
Dim MasterSht As Worksheet
Dim MasterWBShtLstRw As Long
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim TempFile
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
Dim CurrentWBSht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentShtLstRw As Long
Dim CurrentShtRowRef As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim ProjectNumber As String


FolderPath = "d:\test\"
TempFile = Dir(FolderPath)

Dim WkBk As Workbook
Dim WkBkIsOpen As Boolean

'Check is master is open already
For Each WkBk In Workbooks
    If WkBk.Name = "master.xlsm" Then WkBkIsOpen = True
Next WkBk

If WkBkIsOpen Then
    Set MasterWB = Workbooks("master.xlsm")
    Set MasterSht = MasterWB.Sheets("here")
Else
    Set MasterWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "master.xlsm")
    Set MasterSht = MasterWB.Sheets("here")
End If

ProjectNumber = MasterSht.Cells(1, 1).Value



Do While Len(TempFile) > 0

    'Checking that the file is not the master and that it is a xlsx
    If Not TempFile = "master.xlsm" And InStr(1, TempFile, "xlsx", vbTextCompare) Then

        Set CopyRange = Nothing

        'Note this is the last used Row, next empty row will be this plus 1
        With MasterSht
            MasterWBShtLstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        Set CurrentWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & TempFile)
        Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Sheets("Tabelle1")

        With CurrentWBSht
            CurrentShtLstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        For CurrentShtRowRef = 1 To CurrentShtLstRw
        ' If CurrentWBSht.Cells(CurrentShtRowRef, "A").Value = ProjectNumber Then

           'This is set to copy from Column A to Column L as per the question

           If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
             'If there is nothing in Copy range then union wont work
             'so first row of the work sheet needs to set the initial copyrange
              Set CopyRange = CurrentWBSht.Range("A" & CurrentShtRowRef & _
                                            ":AF" & CurrentShtRowRef)
            Else
              'Union is quicker to be able to copy from the sheet once
              Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, CurrentWBSht.Range("A" & CurrentShtRowRef & ":AF" & CurrentShtRowRef))
           End If  ' ending   If CopyRange Is Nothing ....
        ' End If ' ending  If CurrentWBSht.Cells....

        Next CurrentShtRowRef

        CopyRange.Select

        'add 1 to the master file last row to be the next open row
        CopyRange.Copy MasterSht.Cells(MasterWBShtLstRw + 1, 1)

        CurrentWB.Close savechanges:=False

    End If     'ending            If Not TempFile = "zmaster.xlsx" And ....

    TempFile = Dir

        Loop
End Sub
```

I hope I was able to explain my self properly. I would highly appreciate any productive solution.

Comment: what line throws the error? (Incidentally CopyRange.Select is not needed and might be your problem)

Comment: @HarassedDad thank you! 
 yes thats the line that i get the error at but when i remove it i get error in  CopyRange.Copy MasterSht.Cells(MasterWBShtLstRw + 1, 1)

Comment: Don't take it disrespectfully, but reading through your code is a chore! Try to refer to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidlines! In summary: **Try to reduce your code (or better yet, you entire question) only to the issue at hand rather than a full on copy-paste code dump**

Comment: So either CopyRange is nothing, Mastersht is nothing or masterWBshtLstRw is Null  OR copyrange is not a copyable range. Set a break on that line code and use the immediate window to interrogate your variables

Comment: @Rawrplus you are right and sorry for messy situattion, the Problem is i have no idea which part is really useful and which part is not

Comment: @HarassedDad Code works fine on any normal Excel file it only runs into error with my Auto generated sheet

Comment: Are you sure that your auto generated sheets are actually called Tabelle1 - cosd this assumes they are:
Set CurrentWBSht = CurrentWB.Sheets("Tabelle1")

Comment: @HarassedDad Yeah thats because im using a german versian of Excel and Sheets are called Tabelle in german Version.